# Codeigniter mpdf error undefined variable when parsing parameter to pdf file

Tags: codeigniter

I have created pdf file using mpdf in codeigniter. Next, I want to parsing a parameter from controller to view, so in pdf file there's have a `title` text and `image`. I just successfully parsing `image` to pdf, but I'm confused how to parsing text like `title` parameter.

Here's the controller code

```
class Createpdf extends MY_Controller  
{

  function index()
  {
    $image= $this->input->get('image_link');
    $data = "Title Page";
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    $html = $this->load->view('pages/pdfreport',$data,true);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Image($image, 0, 0, 21, 29, 'jpg', '', true);
    $mpdf->Output();
  }
}
```

Here's the view code

```
<center><h3> <?= $data; ?></h3></center>
```

In the pdf file, it shows error `Undefined variable: data`. Do you know how to fixed this ?

Thank you

Comment: use `$this->load->view('pages/pdfreport',array("data" => $data),true); ` send array from here so you'll get $data as variable there.

Comment: Thank you @Mudasirsyed, it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Createpdf extends MY_Controller  
{

  function index()
  {
    $image= $this->input->get('image_link');
    $data = "Title Page";
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    $html = $this->load->view('pages/pdfreport',array("data" => $data),true); 
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Image($image, 0, 0, 21, 29, 'jpg', '', true);
    $mpdf->Output();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Createpdf extends MY_Controller  
{

  function index()
  {
    $image= $this->input->get('image_link');
    $data = ["data" => "Title Page"]; // <-- see here
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    $html = $this->load->view('pages/pdfreport',$data,true);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Image($image, 0, 0, 21, 29, 'jpg', '', true);
    $mpdf->Output();
  }
}
```